# Creating a "swing-o-meter" rotating an image that is inside a pictureBox

Tags: c#, image, rotation, picturebox

so I decided to just jump in with learning to code some more and have managed to get rather stuck since I don't know enough basics *I think*. I have done some work in C and a little in C++ before if that makes any difference.

I decided I wanted to make pointer that is oriented at some angle based on the input. I have everything working bar getting the arrow to rotate. So far I have an arrow bmp image within a pictureBox and the following code which doesn't show up any errors until I build. I'm not entirely sure what else anyone may need to know in order to help so for now I'll just post my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private Bitmap MoveImageByDesiredAngle(int original_width, int original_height, float desiredAngle)
    {
        Bitmap resultPicture = new Bitmap(original_width, original_height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resultPicture);
        g.TranslateTransform((float)original_width / 2, (float)original_height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform(desiredAngle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-(float)original_width / 2, -(float)original_height / 2);
        g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Point(0, 0));
        return resultPicture;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float o;
        float r;

        o = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        r = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);


        float ratio;
        float angle;
        ratio = o / (o + r);
        angle = ratio * 180;

        Bitmap resultPicture = MoveImageByDesiredAngle(pictureBox3.Image.Width, pictureBox3.Image.Height, angle);
        pictureBox3.Image = resultPicture;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem your facing?

Comment: Okay, no idea whats happened but I basically rebuilt everything from scratch, but with the same code and hey presto it works! thanks for your help anyway and sorry for the tagging title thing